# My prefix is in the game, but I just kind of dangle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is in the game, but I just kind of dangle.
> My prefix shouldn't be tipped, but you can give me a bangle.
> My prefix is noble, yet people stab me right through.
> My infix goes far, yet I will never leave you.

What word am I?

Comment: That's a lot of prefixes - are any of those supposed to be a 'suffix', as that part of the word seems to be unclued at present?

Comment: No, I didn't include anything about a suffix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My prefix is in the game, but I just kind of dangle.

> EA is Electronic Arts the video game company, but an earlobe just dangles (if free).

My prefix shouldn't be tipped, but you can give me a bangle.

> ear - it’s not safe to put a Q-Tip in an ear, but can have a ring in your earlobe.

My prefix is noble, yet people stab me right through.

> Earl - a rank of the nobility in the UK, and you can get an earlobe pierced.

My infix goes far, yet I will never leave you.

> lob - throw a ball into a high arch, your earlobe hopefully stays attached!

What word am I?

> You are an [earlobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earlobe)